# .htaccess is ignored on Apache

Tags: apache, .htaccess, configuration

I've made a website in PHP, tested it locally and it works fine. Now I pushed it to my actual webserver and now I'm having trouble, because my `.htaccess` - file should redirect all calls, but it's getting ignored.

This is my `.htaccess` - file

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
    RewriteRule ^(controllers/|core/|models/|views/) - [F,L,NC]
</IfModule>
```

I've already searched for a solution and came up with running these commands:

```
a2enmod rewrite
a2enmod expires
a2ensite default-ssl
```

After each command i restarted the server.

The last command in the list above gives me an error:

```
apache2: Syntax error on line 224 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Syntax error on line 166 of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/default-ssl.conf: Expected </VirtualHost> but saw </IfModule>
Action 'configtest' failed.
```

Does someone have a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Look in your /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/default-ssl.conf file. Does it have one `<VirtualHost>` opening entry without the corresponding `</VirtualHost>` closing entry?